# Combinations Confusion

Tags: combinatorics

Tarang has eight different jigsaws and five different toy bears. He chooses four things to play with. In how many ways can he make a selection with at least two bears?

Using the exclusion principle:

$$^{13}C_{4} - 5*{^8C_3} - {^8C_4} = 365$$

Answer in book: 365

$$^5C_2 * {^{11}C_2} = 550$$

My solution: 550

Both methods seem logical to me, however, evidently result in varying answers. Why is this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are double counting some cases.  Imagine your 5C2 chooses Bear1 and Bear2 and your 11C2 chooses Bear3 and Bear4.  Then later on your 5C2 chooses Bear3 and Bear4 and your 11C2 chooses Bear1 and Bear2 (which it will).  You just double counted that collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your approach some combinations are being counted twice. For example:

Imagine in the $^5C_2$ that you pick bears 1 and 2, you then pick 2 other toys from the remaining 11. Some of these picks will include bear 3.

Then imagine in the $^5C_2$ you pick bears 1 and 3. You then pick 2 other toys from the remaining 11. Some of these picks will include bear 2.

If you want to do it without exclusion you would need to do it additively:

$$^5C_2\cdot\space^8C_2 +^5C_3\cdot\space^8C_1 +^5C_4\cdot\space^8C_0 $$